# Merge two columns in the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with multiple pairs of columns that have to be merged. The columns contain mutually exclusive data. That is, if there is a value in Column A, the value for that row in Column B will be empty.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
               'A': ['A0', '', 'A2', ''],
               'B': ['', 'B1', '', 'B3'],
               'C': ['C1','C2','',''],
               'D': ['','','D3','D4']})
```

So I have something like this:

```
    A   B   C   D key
0  A0      C1      K0
1      B1  C2      K1
2  A2          D3  K2
3      B3      D4  K3
```

I'd like to merge columns A and B so all values end up in column A. I also want to do this form C and D, while keeping the index and any other columns such as Key untouched. I'm fine doing this in multiple steps. I don't need to do A-B merge and the C-D merge at the same time. Ideally, I would end up with:

```
    A   C key
0  A0  C1  K0
1  B1  C2  K1
2  A2  D3  K2
3  B3  D4  K3
```

I've tried `df = df.A.combine_first(df.B)` but that gets me nowhere.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'A': df.A + df.B, 'C': df.C + df.D, 'key': df.key})` is essentially what @Bharath has done dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using zip to match every two columns

```
li = zip(df.columns[0::2],df.columns[1::2])
#[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D')] 
# I assume columns are pairs and end up with lenght as odd number with additional column.
# If you want to ignore last column manually you can use 
# li = zip(df.columns[0:-1:2],df.columns[1:-1:2]) # slice `start:end:step`

temp = pd.DataFrame({i :df[i]+df[j] for i,j in li})

ndf = pd.concat([temp,df['key']],1)

#    A   C key
# 0  A0  C1  K0
# 1  B1  C2  K1
# 2  A2  D3  K2
# 3  B3  D4  K3
```

Comment: Thanks, Bharath. That's quick and clean.

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with converting the empty strings to NaN first you could try using [Series.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by doing something like this:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.nan)

df.A = df.A.fillna(df.B)
df.C = df.C.fillna(df.D)
```

which gives:

```
df

    A    B   C    D key
0  A0  NaN  C1  NaN  K0
1  B1   B1  C2  NaN  K1
2  A2  NaN  D3   D3  K2
3  B3   B3  D4   D4  K3
```

Which will fill the missing values in column A with those in column B then set the resulting series to column A in `df`. We can extend this idea for the case of multiple columns by using a loop:

```
l_cols = df.columns[0::2]  # Left columns in the pairs
r_cols = df.columns[1::2]  # Right columns in the pairs  

# Go through each pair
for l, r in zip(l_cols, r_cols):
    df[l] = df[r].fillna(df[r])
```

The columns used for merging can be excluded from the output using:

```
df = df.drop(r_cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: You can also make use or Dropna(1) rather than selecting manually

Comment: And the problem is if you have 1000 pairs or columns

Comment: Thanks @Bharath. Should be fixed now.